# how to retrieve the data from the onMetadataUpdated() while casting?

Tags: android, metadata, chromecast

i need to retrieve the some data(Custom Data) from the receiver app then only i can update my sender App UI in Mobile, I just passed the CustomData to receiver app while connecting to the `Chromecast` device which is working fine. i found the `mRemoteMediaPlayer.setOnMetadataUpdatedListener` but where how can i get the custom data from the receiver?.

Thanks in Advance

my Code part is

```
if (mRemoteMediaPlayer == null || !mApiClient.isConnected()) {
            Toast.makeText(this.ctx, "No Connection", Toast.LENGTH_LONG)
                    .show();
            return;
        }
        MediaMetadata mediaMetadata = new MediaMetadata(
                MediaMetadata.MEDIA_TYPE_MUSIC_TRACK);
        mediaMetadata.putString(MediaMetadata.KEY_ALBUM_ARTIST, ""
                + singers.getText().toString());
        mediaMetadata.putString(mediaMetadata.KEY_ALBUM_TITLE, ""
                + songTitle.getText().toString());
        mediaMetadata
                .addImage(new WebImage(Uri.parse(cdImgurlList.get(0))));

MediaInfo mediaInfo = new MediaInfo.Builder(songUrl)
                .setContentType("audio/mp3")
                .setStreamType(MediaInfo.STREAM_TYPE_BUFFERED)
                .setCustomData(customjsonArrayWrapper)    //here pass the customData to the receiver.
                .setMetadata(mediaMetadata).build();
        mRemoteMediaPlayer
                .load(mApiClient, mediaInfo, true)
                .setResultCallback(
                        new ResultCallback<RemoteMediaPlayer.MediaChannelResult>() {

                            @Override
                            public void onResult(MediaChannelResult result) {
                                if (result.getStatus().isSuccess()) {
                                    Log.d(TAG, "Media loaded Successfully"
                                            + result.getStatus());
                                    Toast.makeText(
                                            RaagaActivity.this,
                                            "Media Channel loaded Successfully"
                                                    + result.getStatus(),
                                            Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                                    // Update the UI While chrome casting
                                    UpdateUIControlsinCasting();

                                } else {
                                    Log.d(TAG,
                                            "Media loaded Not Successfully"
                                                    + result.getStatus());
                                    Toast.makeText(
                                            RaagaActivity.this,
                                            "Media Channel not loaded Successfully"
                                                    + result.getStatus(),
                                            Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                                }
                            }
                        });

    } catch (IllegalStateException e) {
        String err = (e.getMessage()==null)?"IllegalStateException":e.getMessage();
        Log.e(TAG, err);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        // TODO: handle exception
        String err = (e.getMessage()==null)?"Exception":e.getMessage();
        Log.e(TAG, err);
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to retrieve the custom data when metadata updates, try the following: when `onMetadataUpdated()` of `OnMetadataUpdateListener` is called, get the `MediaInfo` by calling `mediaInfo = mRemoteMediaPlayer.getMediaInfo()` and then get the custom data via `mediaIfo.getCustomData()`.

Comment: Thank you for Your Response, I will try this and let You know.

Comment: Hi Naddaf, Actually i was sent list of the songs through by setCustomData(json objects) and there are automatically playing continuously on TV, but what i need, i have to update my app UI(Song tittle, Image) when started to play next song on TV. i am getting customData  when load the first song and not get when play the next song that means the onMetadataUpdated() doesn't call at next song playing on TV, how to detect the next song playing on TV? then only i can update the song information in my app

Comment: It seems like you have written a custom receiver, so you need to make sure the metadata update is sent when a new media loads; you can get some idea fro this sample project: https://github.com/googlecast/CastVideosPlaylist-chrome